# Varias computadoras trabajar como 1

Tags: apache-spark, cluster

tengo varios computadoras un poco antiguas botadas , y quería saber de que forma podría alinearlas en una especie de cluster, para poder correar aplicaciones de una manera mas "veloz" por así decirlo ,en la que se pueda repartir la carga de trabajo,etc , viendo algunas opciones quizas con apacher spark podría hacerlo , sin embargo,que otras opciones hay?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que a lo que te refieres es al "cómputo distribuido" o "distributed computing" en inglés. Actualmente existen varios frameworks que te permiten ejecutar tareas utilizando varias computadoras.

La herramienta [jppf](http://www.jppf.org/) está diseñada para cumplir con los propósitos mencionados, de igual manera, en [este post](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-some-of-the-most-famous-distributed-computing-frameworks) se nombran a muchas otras, espero te resulte útil.

Saludos.